# Matplotlib alternative to fill_betweenx()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the functionality of fill_betweenx() without having to use the function itself, because it doesn't accept the interpolate parameter. I need the interpolate functionality that is supported by fill_between(), but for the filling to happen relative to the x axis. It sounds like the interpolate parameter will be supported for fill_betweenx() in matplotlib 2.1, but it would be great to have access to the functionality via a workaround in the meantime.

This is the line of code in question:

```
ax4.fill_betweenx(x,300,p, where=p>=150, interpolate=True, facecolor='White', lw=1, zorder=2)
```

Unfortunately this gives me AttributeError: Unknown property interpolate.

Comment: Maybe you could use `np.interp` to interpolate your data before passing it to `fill_betweenx`

Answer (score 0):

One lazy way to do it is to use the `fill_between()` function with inverted coordinates on a figure that you don't show (i.e. close the figure before using `plt.show()`), and then re-use the vertices of the `PolyCollection` that `fill_between()` returns on your actual plot. It's not perfect, but it works as a quick fix. Here an example of what I'm talking about:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import numpy as np

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols =2, figsize=(8,8))

#the data
x = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,3)
y = np.sin(x)

#fill_between without interpolation
ax = axes[0,0]
ax.plot(x,y,'k')
ax.fill_between(x,0.5,y,where=y>0.25)

#fill_between with interpolation, keep the PolyCollection
ax = axes[0,1]
ax.plot(x,y,'k')
poly_col = ax.fill_between(x,0.5,y,where=y>0.25,interpolate=True)

#fill_betweenx -- no interpolation possible
ax = axes[1,0]
ax.plot(y,x,'k')
ax.fill_betweenx(x,0.5,y,where=y>0.25)

#faked fill_betweenx:
ax = axes[1,1]
ax.plot(y,x,'k')

#get the vertices from the saved PolyCollection, swap x- and y-values
v=poly_col.get_paths()[0].vertices

#convert to correct format
v2=list(zip(v[:,1],v[:,0]))

#and add to axes
ax.add_collection(PolyCollection([v2]))

#voila
plt.show()
```

The result of the code looks like this:

[image: result of the code]